# ffmpeg - line_h option not found in latest version of ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to use the option line_h of drawtext filter, with last build of ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg version N-45325-gb173e0353-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx     --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56.  9.100 / 56.  9.100
  libavcodec     58. 14.100 / 58. 14.100
  libavformat    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavdevice    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavfilter     7. 13.100 /  7. 13.100
  libswscale      5.  0.102 /  5.  0.102
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
Input #0, image2, from 'source/img001.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 12723 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1024x768 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[Parsed_drawtext_4 @ 0x45699c0] Option 'line_h' not found
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x4581440] Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'fontfile=Roboto-Regular.ttf:enable=between(t,0,6):line_h=20:text=
```

I'm talking about this filter option:

```
line_h, lh
the height of each text line
```

Is this a deprecated feature? how is possible that this option is not found in last version of ffmpeg?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`line_h` is not an option. It is a variable that can be used in expressions and its value is the height of the tallest character in the text.